# Chinese remainder theorem - RSA

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography, chinese-remainder-theorem

The following is a excerpt from RSA Decryption correctness [proof](http://www.leahhoward.com/m222/222online_RSA.pdf) (section 4) :

> $$\begin{align}
> C^d &\equiv M\pmod {p} \tag{1}\\
> C^d &\equiv M\pmod {q} \tag{2}
> \end{align}$$
>   Now by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ ($p$ and $q$ are
>   different primes), there is exactly one number mod $pq$ that has properties
>   $(1)$ and $(2)$ – it is $M \pmod{pq}$. So $C^d\equiv M\pmod {pq}$.

***Question :*** How is that number $M\pmod {pq}$ ?

Comment: Well, do you understand the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: I think I do. The constructive proof involved inverses but I could not follow it to the above conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$M$ is an integer. Suppose $X$ is ***some*** integer with the property that
$$X\equiv M\bmod p,\qquad X\equiv M\bmod q.$$
The Chinese remainder theorem then says that if $Y$ is ***any*** integer such that
$$Y\equiv M\bmod p,\qquad Y\equiv M\bmod q$$
then $Y\equiv X\bmod pq$. But obviously, $M$ is an integer with the property that
$$M\equiv M\bmod p,\qquad M\equiv M\bmod q.$$
Therefore, any $Y$ such that
$$Y\equiv M\bmod p,\qquad Y\equiv M\bmod q$$
must satisfy $Y\equiv M\bmod pq$.

Comment: I realize my dumbness. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

$p$ and $q$ being two different primes, there exists two integers $m,n$ such that
$$
 mp-nq=1
$$

Your two equations can also be rewritten

$$
 C^d = M +\alpha p \\
 C^d = M + \beta q
$$

Multiplying the first by $-nq$ and the second by $mp$ and summing them, we get 
$$
 (mp-nq)C^d = (mp-nq)M + (\beta m-\alpha n)pq
$$
And now returning to a modular expression you get
$$
 C^d = M \mod {pq}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As $gcd(p,q) =1$, we have a group isomorphism
$$
\pi: \mathbb Z / pq \rightarrow \mathbb Z / p \times \mathbb Z / q, \ x + pq \mathbb Z \mapsto (x + p \mathbb Z, x + q \mathbb Z)
$$

You're looking for some $M + pq \mathbb Z \in \mathbb Z$ that satifies $\pi (M + pq \mathbb Z) = (C^d + p \mathbb Z, C^d + q \mathbb Z)$. By the above such a value $M$ exists and is unique.